# PHP cache control

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have recently started some cache control on my website and it seems like some of the functions have stopped working because of this.
My PHP content doesn't update anymore. In the Chrome network tool, I can see that some of the PHP script request sizes are (from cache). I tried refreshing the page but it still didn't update. It only updated when I deleted the whole cache data from Chrome. I tried deleting what I did in .htaccess but it didn't update anyway. How do I state that PHP scripts should not be held in cache? 
Currently, a javascript file uses ajax with GET method for these PHP scripts to update some HTML text which doesn't update anymore.

My .htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType audio/mp3                 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 year"

ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 2 days"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript           "access plus 1 year"

# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType font/truetype             "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

<FilesMatch ".(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

This is how it was before (when everything was working):
[image: before]

This is how it is now:
[image: after]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is my cache configuration who work really well:

```
# MOD_DEFLATE COMPRESSION
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application$

# DEFLATE NOT COMPATIBLE BROWERS
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# NOT CHACHING IF ALREADY CACHED
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip

# EXPIRE HEADERS
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
#Images
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
AddType image/x-icon .ico
ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
#Elements
ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 week"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 week"
#Others
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</IfModule>

# CACHE-CONTROL HEADERS
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch "\\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|gz|ttf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2797200, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(css)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2797200, public"
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\\.(js)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2797200, private"
</FilesMatch>
<filesMatch "\\.(html|htm)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public"
</filesMatch>
# Disable caching for scripts and other dynamic files
<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

all is cached and compressed except dynamic content.

based on 
http://www.seomix.fr/guide-htaccess-performances-et-temps-de-chargement/

to force php header you can do this

```
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
     Header unset ETag
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Sat, 2 Aug 1980 15:15:00 GMT"

     ExpiresActive On
     ExpiresDefault "access plus 0 seconds"
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code but the PHP requests still come from cache somehow. I have "<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="public">" in my index page. Could this be the problem?

Comment: `Header unset Cache-Control` should remove cache control are you sure `mod_headers` is installed, as your page is already cached, you might have to wait cache expire to remake test, or remove browser caching and remake test

Comment: Thank you very much. I was using Chrome's incognito mode to test it. I thought it didn't use cache but turns out it does. I'm not even sure if the second part of your code was necessary to fix this.

Comment: Please why did you put ```<FilesMatch "\\.``` (two slashes instead of one) at some places. Please what is the rule that cause you to add only one slash at a certain place ?